# XSLT xsl:sort issue

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I have an XML file that I need to sort. Worked great until the dev consuming it told me to change the XML to items that I had with attributes of type=label to label nodes. Not great at XSLT. Need to sort on the 'sort' node.

The (simplified) XML looks like this:

```
<rss>
   <channel>
       <title>This is the title</title>
       <link>http://www.mydomain.com/</link>
       <description>The Description</description>
       <label>
           <title>Another Label</title>
           <sort>4</sort>
       </label>
       <item>
           <title>An Item</title>
           <sort>2</sort>
       </item>
       <item>
           <title>One Item</title>
           <sort>3</sort>
       </item>
       <label>
           <title>A Label</title>
           <sort>1</sort>
       </label>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

The old XSL (when I was just sorting 'items') looks something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
     <xsl:template match="channel">
        <rss>
           <channel>
              <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="description"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
                  <xsl:sort select="sort" data-type="number"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
           </channel>
        </rss>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template> 
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tried this thinking it would work and it mostly does, but I get all sorts of "stragglers".

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="channel">
    <rss>
      <channel>
        <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="description"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="sort"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
      </channel>
    </rss>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="label">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The "stragglers" look like this when all is said and done using the latest XSL:

```
<rss xmlns:st="http://ww2.startribune.com/rss/modules/base/">
  <channel>
    <title>A Title</title>
    <link>http://www.mydomain.com/</link>
    <description>The Description</description>
A Title
http://www.mydomain.com/
The Description
        <label>...
    <item>...
```

Comment: The "stragglers" happen due to the default matching template XSLT engines provide.   Since you explicitly process title, link, and description elements in the channel template, you need to create emptry templates for them to suck up the text.  Your general apply-templates call is the reason the default template is getting triggered.

Comment: @ewh - You should post your comment as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @ewh - What do these empty templates look like and where do they go? I understand what the "apply-templates" did with the select=item, and see what it's doing now. How can I have it sort the labels and the items together based on the common "sort" child node?

Comment: See my answer for a more semantically correct solution that relies on standard `xsl:sort` behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="channel">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:sort select="sort" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<rss>
    <channel>
        <title>This is the title</title>
        <link>http://www.mydomain.com/</link>
        <description>The Description</description>
        <label>
            <title>A Label</title>
            <sort>1</sort>
        </label>
        <item>
            <title>An Item</title>
            <sort>2</sort>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>One Item</title>
            <sort>3</sort>
        </item>
        <label>
            <title>Another Label</title>
            <sort>4</sort>
        </label>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

**Note**: Identity rule. Sorting `channel` childrens: `NaN` values for a number sorting key come first. Althought this is normal behavior, it wasn't until XSLT 2.0 that this was explicitly defined, from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#comparing-sort-keys :

> NaN values, for sorting purposes, are
>   considered to be equal to each other,
>   and less than any other numeric value.

**EDIT**: I wasn't sure, but after searching, this is also part of XSLT 1.0 spec in [errata document](http://www.w3.org/1999/11/REC-xslt-19991116-errata/#E20):

> in ascending order a NaN precedes all
>   other numeric values and in descending
>   order it follows them

Answer (score 3):

XSLT provides a default matching template for nodes, where the textual content of the node is outputed.

In the XSLT you provide, you already processing elements title, link, and description in your channel template, you need to create empty templates to suck them up due to your apply-templates call in your channel template.  For example:

```
<xsl:template match="title|link|description"/>
```

This should suck up your "stragglers".

Comment: Thanks for this. Very helpful. Starting to understand a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to 'hard-code' the names of specific 'stragglers', which would be otherwise picked up by the default matching template, you could add you own default template in this case, to simply ignore such nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

This matches any non-specific node, and simply ignores it, and carries on processing the child nodes (so that when it matches the 'rss' node, it can then go on to match the 'channel' node). You specific template matches for 'channel', 'item' and 'label' will take priority over this.

Thus, if you take the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

   <xsl:template match="channel">
      <rss>
         <channel>
            <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="description"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
               <xsl:sort select="sort"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </channel>
      </rss>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="label">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And apply it to your simplified XML, you should get the following output

```
<rss>
   <channel>
      <title>This is the title</title>
      <link>http://www.mydomain.com/</link>
      <description>The Description</description>
      <label>
         <title>A Label</title>
         <sort>1</sort>
      </label>
      <item>
         <title>An Item</title>
         <sort>2</sort>
      </item>
      <item>
         <title>One Item</title>
         <sort>3</sort>
      </item>
      <label>
         <title>Another Label</title>
         <sort>4</sort>
      </label>
   </channel>
</rss>
```